# How to deal with missing values in python scikit NMF

Tags: python, scikit-learn, recommendation-engine, matrix-factorization, nmf

I am trying to apply NMF on my dataset, using python `scikit-learn`. My dataset contains 0 values and missing values. But `scikit-learn` does not allow NaN value in data matrix. Some posts said that replace missing values with zeros.

my questions are:

- If I replace missing value with zeros, how can the algorithm tell the missing values and real zero values?
- Is there any other NMF implementations can deal with missing values?
- Or if there are any other matrix factorization algorithms can do the missing value prediction?

Comment: The replacement of missing-values with zero (or column-mean, or row-mean or ...) is not known by the classifier. It will treat these numbers as any other which might be okay (we are always assuming a low-rank model exists with these methods). / In general i would say, that missing-value prediction is a harder problem (which needs stronger assumptions) compared to finding a low-rank factorization of a matrix without missing-values. As an alternative: write a SGD-based optimizer for some common nmf-problem (and you can sample from the known values only)

Comment: Thanks, it seems ignoring missing values when applying SGD is the solution.

Comment: Facing the same problem. Have you written your own SGD implementation? If yes, how is it performing? So far I have not been able to achieve anything that performs similar to NMF.

Comment: @silentser Yes I have tried my own SGD implementation. It has similar performance compared with sklearn implementation, but much slower.

Answer (score 3):

There is a thread about this in scikit-learn github and a version seams to be available but not yet commited to the main code.

https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/pull/8474

Comment: Please add more info.  Links expire.

Answer (score 1):

SGD will do the job here, but scikit-learn does not have one that could be applied for the task. Writing your own one will do the job, but will be *really* slow since one cannot directly parallelise matrix factorization SGD. 
Check *Distributed SGD* algorithm described [here](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.230.7682&rep=rep1&type=pdf). It is not so hard to implement and it speeds up things significantly.

Comment: The link seems broken. Is this the same one as your original? http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.230.7682&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Answer (score 0):

For some usecases, replacing the missing ratings by some sort of average values (e.g., of nearest neighbors) prior to using `sklearn.decomposition.nmf()` (which does not accept `NaN` values) may be useful.

For example, consider the item-item collaborative filtering as low-rank matrix factorization problem, to be solved using `non-negative matrix factorization`.

The next code snippet

- first randomly generates a toy user-item ratings dataset with missing entries.
- next it imputes the missing ratings for any item using the average rating for the item.
- after that the matrix is reconstructed using `NMF`.

It achieves low RMSE for reconstruction.

```
nusers = 10
nitems = 5

# generate nusers x nitems matrix for ratings
np.random.seed(1)
ratings = np.random.choice(range(1,6), nusers*nitems).reshape(nusers, nitems).astype(np.float64)
missing = np.random.choice(range(0,2), nusers*nitems, p=[0.4,0.6]).reshape(nusers, nitems).astype(bool)
ratings[missing] = np.nan

ratings  # user-item rating matrix with missing entries
#array([[nan, nan, nan,  2., nan],
#       [ 1., nan, nan,  5.,  5.],
#       [ 2.,  3., nan,  3.,  5.],
#       [nan,  5., nan,  5., nan],
#       [nan,  2., nan, nan, nan],
#       [ 2., nan, nan, nan, nan],
#       [nan, nan,  1.,  4., nan],
#       [ 2.,  1., nan,  2., nan],
#       [nan, nan, nan, nan,  4.],
#       [ 5., nan, nan, nan, nan]])
```

Now fill the missing values with mean item ratings

```
# fill NaN values with mean item ratings
mean_item_rating = np.nanmean(ratings, axis=0)
inds = np.where(np.isnan(ratings))
ratings[inds] = np.take(mean_item_rating, inds[1])
```

Fit `NMF` model on the imputed ratings and reconstruct.

```
k = 2 # number of latent features
nmf = decomposition.NMF(
    n_components=k, 
    random_state=0, 
    init = "nndsvda", 
    beta_loss="frobenius",
    alpha_W=0.001,
    alpha_H=0.001,
    )

W1 = nmf.fit_transform(ratings)
H1 = nmf.components_
# nmf.reconstruction_err_
pred = W1 @ H1
```

Here is the reconstructed matrix:

```
pred # reconstructed ratings matrix with nmf
#array([[2.7538703 , 2.21530206, 0.91599971, 2.74505676, 4.24230709],
#       [1.25524759, 3.59251295, 0.97033684, 4.66032356, 4.61479129],
#       [2.35280766, 2.78126364, 0.97279116, 3.51816793, 4.54689907],
#       [1.84354306, 3.98096118, 1.14786757, 5.13481057, 5.4330296 ],
#       [2.53186319, 2.57236077, 0.95680549, 3.23078732, 4.45635212],
#       [2.15528539, 2.83261418, 0.95209144, 3.59878839, 4.46086756],
#       [2.33351068, 2.97179146, 1.01047576, 3.77090889, 4.73106912],
#       [2.68816785, 1.77452768, 0.81111479, 2.16752937, 3.73840089],
#       [2.19156078, 2.64733105, 0.91825346, 3.3518664 , 4.29411891],
#       [4.28014936, 2.45802613, 1.21283129, 2.96621938, 5.57095048]])
```

Finally compare with the initial ratings matrix with missing values.

```
pred[missing] = np.nan # mask the reconstructed missing ratings, for the ease of comparison 
np.sqrt(np.sum((ratings[~missing] - pred[~missing])**2) / (np.sum(~missing))) # rmse
# 0.49721783850318846

pred
#array([[       nan,        nan,        nan, 2.74505676,        nan],
#       [1.25524759,        nan,        nan, 4.66032356, 4.61479129],
#       [2.35280766, 2.78126364,        nan, 3.51816793, 4.54689907],
#       [       nan, 3.98096118,        nan, 5.13481057,        nan],
#       [       nan, 2.57236077,        nan,        nan,        nan],
#       [2.15528539,        nan,        nan,        nan,        nan],
#       [       nan,        nan, 1.01047576, 3.77090889,        nan],
#       [2.68816785, 1.77452768,        nan, 2.16752937,        nan],
#       [       nan,        nan,        nan,        nan, 4.29411891],
#       [4.28014936,        nan,        nan,        nan,        nan]])
```

Now compare the matrix `ratings` and the reconstructed matrix `pred` in terms of the ratings already present, they are pretty close (with low `RMSE`).